# What are my current privileges?

Tags: support

For many seasoned StackExchange users we have enough rep that we no longer check our privileges and over the years have forgotten how, count me in.

As this moves from private beta to public beta and finally into a standard site the reputation one needs will change.

To check on your current privileges and see what comes next click the following link

https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

---

I had to tag this with something so used discussion.

Think of this as more of a nice to know and bookmark in you browser before you forget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Answer (score 4):

Note that when the site moves out of private beta (usually within a few weeks), the reputation needed for most privileges will change as well. Everything is documented on Meta Stack Exchange: [What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/295232)

Most notably (for users with the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/295232)):

- Voting (right now, most users can upvote, downvote, vote to close and vote to reopen - after the transition, they can only upvote)
- Creating tags (right now, everybody can do that, but it will require 150 reputation)

Comment: @GuyCoder I think that's true for both private and public betas?